# Java: My JFrame's contents (buttons etc.) are not clickable when I start my server

Tags: java, swing, jframe, server

I have created a simple HTTP server in Java by using a ServerSocket that accepts browser requests. The server is working fine without any errors. I have created a JForm using Swing that contains buttons to start and stop the server.
In the start button I have added an ActionListener that runs my ServerMain class.

```
JButton btnStartServer = new JButton("Start Server");
    panel.add(btnStartServer);
    btnStartServer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            try {
                ServerMain.main(new String[0]);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Whenever i start the server though, my JFrame becomes unclickable, and so I cannot click the Exit button which contains this code:

```
JButton btnExit = new JButton("Exit");
    panel.add(btnExit);
    btnExit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            try {
                System.exit(0);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });;
```

The socket listening and accepting for connections through a loop must be the cause of this but I have no idea of how to fix it.
Any suggestions would be brilliant.
Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As **Swing** components are not thread safe, all UI actions are performed in special thread called **Event Dispatcher Thread** (EDT) (this technique called **thread confinement**).

So you start **ServerMain** in EDT, that's why any subsequent actions will not perform.

To avoid such problem you should run blocking operations in separated thread. So rough solution to your problem:

```
btnStartServer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        try {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() { 
                    ServerMain.main(new String[0]);
                }
             }).start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

I recommend you to read about Java [concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/), than you can read about [concurrency model in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html).

Comment: In addition to balalaika's excellent answer (1+), this type of code: `ServerMain.main(new String[0]);` suggests that you could connect your two programs better and allow cleaner OOP-compliant interactions.

Comment: Excellent answer balalaika, thank you so much man! Brilliant explanation!

Comment: And/or consider a [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html), depending on what you are trying to do